# LaTexTools stops compiling in Sublime Text

Tags: compiling, sublime-text

I have been using LaTexTools for a while, and it works fine. After installing the public beta of Yosemite, Sublime Text + LatexTools stops working: the `build` command brings up output window showing NO errors:

```
[Compiling /Users/.../sometexfile.tex]

TraditionalBuilder: Invoking latexmk... done.

No errors. Warnings:
```

It generates `.aux` and `fdb_latexmk` files, but not others, including PDF.

TexShop works fine, and if I compile with TexShop to generate a PDF, the forward/backward sync works in Sublime Text + Skim.

I wonder is there any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an answer in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149254/latextools-sublime-text-3-does-not-compile-after-installing-yosemite-public-b

In the preference menu, go to LaTexTools's Settings - User, change

```
"builder": "traditional"
```

to

```
"builder": "simple"
```

Comment: Can you double-check that link? It doesn't look right.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell: Do you mean the link itself does not work (on my browser it does work), or the method described is not working? Anyway, I think in the released version of Yosemite `LaTexTools` works fine, no need for such tweak.

Comment: No, your original post linked to an unrelated post, until @doed fixed it. The released version of Yosemite doesn't fix the underlying problem, but `LaTeXTools` has worked around it.

Comment: Lelouch, @AdamMaxwell is correct. The original link you posted, was wrong. I can't confirm though, whether your answer is correct, as I don't have a system to test it with, at the moment.