# OS X Yosemite - LaTeXTools plugin of Sublime Text broken

Tags: mac, sublime-text

I upgraded my OS X to Yosemite yesterday, and after that, all the images I included using \includegraphics won't show up in the output document, nor do they occupy any space! I tried to compile the same .tex file on sharelatex and the images show up perfectly, so I'm quite sure it's not some error in my code. Anyone else having the same issue? I remember there was a lengthy process by OS X backing up files and later restoring them during the upgrade process, in which TeX files were also involved. I wonder whether something was broken during the process. Will reinstalling TeX distribution help?

### EDIT:

I realized it was a problem with LaTeXTools plugin of Sublime Text, which has [become broken](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/401) and won't output an updated doucment, instead of my TeX distribution. The file compiles fine with TexShop. The the question should be is there any fix for LaTeXTools to let it compile correctly.

Comment: What does the log file say about the images?

Comment: Please post an MWE and indicate which format (pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or some other format) you use.

Comment: Well I realized it was actually a problem regarding the LaTeXTools plugin of SublimeText. It has [become broken in Yosemite](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/401). Not the problem of tex distribution on my system.

Comment: Well there is even a sublime-text tag right here on tex.stackexchange.

Comment: You know the drill: Post an MWE that generates the problem behavior.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195015/latextools-stops-compiling-in-sublime-text/195412#195412