# SublimeText2 LaTeXTools won't produce pdf

Tags: compiling, sublime-text

I'm using SublimeText2 with LaTeXTools on Ubuntu 14.04LTS and TeXLive 2015.

When I press ctrl+b, it generates the `.aux` and `dfb_latexmk` file but no pdf. My problem was described in a previous post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195015/latextools-stops-compiling-in-sublime-text). The suggested solution does not work for me (changing the builder to simple).

I've also tried to delete everything except the `.tex` file and recompile, with the same result. I tried Tools-->Build System-->LaTeX, but I get the same results. I tried the platform-specific recommendations in the LaTeXTools recommendations (i.e., removing the space in `= 'E` and quoting `$pdflatex` command); but they didn't seem to work.

The problem is not with a specific file. When I ran ctrl+b on a TeX file I wrote a while ago, it shows the pdf; but if I try to change the file, it shows the same pdf (i.e. the pdf is not changed to reflect the changes I made in the file). I assume it uses the already-complied pdf and does not compile a new one.

Running `latexmk test.tex -pdf` from command line works without a problem.

Here is a snippet from the console of ST2:

```
    <class 'traditionalBuilder.TraditionalBuilder'>
    Welcome to thread Thread-4
    2
    [u'/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/latexmk', u'-cd', u'-e', u"$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O'", u'-f', u'-pdf', u'test.tex']
    Finished normally
    12
    Exception in thread Thread-4:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
      File "./makePDF.py", line 164, in run
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/.../test.log'
```

**EDIT** In response to ig0774 suggestion, here is the output of latexmk

```
`Stdout:

Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 5 February 2015, version: 4.43a.
Latexmk: Changing directory to './'
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
  'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'q/pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1  -recorder  "test.tex"/'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
sh: 1: q/pdflatex: not found
Failure to make 'test.pdf'
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'test.log'
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'test.tex':
   (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'test.log'
Latexmk: Undoing directory change
Latexmk: Errors, in force_mode: so I tried finishing targets`
```

Changing back to `"command" : ["/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/latexmk", "-cd", "-e", "$pdflatex = '%E -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O'", "-f", "-pdf"]` I get the following stdout:

```
`Stdout:

Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 5 February 2015, version: 4.43a.
Latexmk: Changing directory to './'
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'test.pdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 "test.tex"  -recorder '
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
sh: 1: pdflatex: not found
Failure to make 'test.pdf'
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'test.log'
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'test.tex':
   (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'test.log'
Latexmk: Undoing directory change
Latexmk: Errors, in force_mode: so I tried finishing targets`
```

Comment: Try deleting the pdf, and recompile. It worked with me before. If that doesn't work, delete all files except the .tex file and recompile. By the way, Sublime Text 3 is available, I don't remember the build now though. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Alenanno Thank you. I forgot to mention that I already tried that; I'll edit the question.

Comment: Be aware with two details:
1. You really are using SublimeText2 not 3. I have Sublime Text 3 installed in my notebook and works fine with LatexMk but it can't connect with evince for open automatically the PDF view. But here in the workstation Sublime Text 2 works fine.
2. Ensure your LaTeXTools package is updated and the build system is the correct one. Most of time the automatic build works fine, but if it's not your case try to use the specific one for LaTeX. Take a look at the package documentation.

Comment: @Aradnix Thanks. I've edited my question to adress your suggestions.

Comment: What happens when you run `latexmk` from the console on the same file? Basically, in your console output, the 12 after the line "Finished normally" is the exit code of latexmk, which seems to indicate some sort of error in latexmk itself.

Comment: @ig0774 Thank you for the comment. When I ran `latexmk` from the console I get no error messages. `.aux`, `.dvi` (empty though!), `.fdb_latexmk`, `.fls` and `.log` files are produced.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools#latex-plugin-for-sublime-text-2-and-3) there you can find a note that says `https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools#latex-plugin-for-sublime-text-2-and-3` read it carefully, perhaps that can be helpful.

Comment: @Gal: can you try running `latexmk -gg -pdf test`, just to see what happens then... Also can you compile other tex documents using either latexmk or Sublime?

Comment: @ig0774 Thanks again for the comment. Running `latexmk test.tex -pdf` from command line works flawlessly and produces a `.pdf` (as well as `.log` and all other expected files). So does `latex -gg -pdf test`. I can also compile other tex documents using `latexmk` from command line, but not using Sublime.

Comment: @Gal: Is your log file generated in the same folder as the test.tex? And is it named test.log?

Comment: @ig0774 Yes, same folder, proper name and no errors.

Comment: Have you tried running the exact command quoted in the log, `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/latexmk -cd -e "$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O'" -f -pdf test.tex` ?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thank you! Trying the command from the terminal I get the following error:

`Latexmk: Stopping because executing following code from command line
     = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O'
gave an error:
    syntax error at (eval 7) line 1, near "="`

I've tried removing spaces as in `"pdflatex='pdflatex ...'"`, but I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: After looking at the latexmk manual... try `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/latexmk -cd -e '$pdflatex = q/pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O/' -f -pdf test.tex` and `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/latexmk -cd -e '$pdflatex = q/pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S/' -f -pdf test.tex` (changing quotes, reversing %O and %S).

Comment: FYI, the author of LatexTools, @marciano-siniscalchi, has an account [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/33204/marciano-siniscalchi). Perhaps you can somehow notify him of this issue.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yep! Both of these work from the command line. However, they don't work for Sublime. Here is what I tried: in builder setting, after `"linux" : {},` I added `"command" : ["/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/latexmk", "-cd", "-e", "$pdflatex = 'q/pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S/'", "-f", "-pdf"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a comment not a question, but it's too long to fit into the comment field.

Let's try to get the output from `latexmk` when its run through Sublime Text since it seems to be different from running `latexmk` from the console. To do this we'll need to modify your local copy of `makePDF.py`.

To find this file:

- In Sublime Text, run the **Preferences: Browse Packages** command
- Find the LaTeXTools folder
- Open `makePDF.py` in Sublime Text (or an editor of your choice)

To edit this file:

- Go to line 164. It should be `data = open(self.caller.tex_base + ".log", 'rb').read()`
- Replace line 164 with this block of code:

  ```
  content = ['']
  if out is not None:
      content.extend(['Stdout:', '', out.decode('utf-8')])
  if err is not None:
      content.extend(['Stderr:', '', err.decode('utf-8')])
  self.caller.output(content)

  try:
      data = open(self.caller.tex_base + ".log", 'rb').read()
  except IOError:
      self.caller.finish(False)
      return
  ```

**NB**: all the spacing should be tabs and the code should be indented to line up with the comments.

After doing this, re-run the compilation. It will give you the output from `latexmk`. Post that here and we might be able to better diagnose the issue.

---

So it seems as if there's a mismatch between the `$PATH` on your console and the `$PATH` visible to Sublime Text, so that `pdflatex` is not visible to the Sublime Text path. (I'm assuming that, since it works from the console, that `pdflatex` is actually installed on your machine and that you haven't touched the `texpath` setting to remvoe `$PATH` from it). So:

- From the console, run `which pdflatex`
- Add the folder containing `pdflatex` to the `texpath` setting in platform settings bit of `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings`.

Try re-compiling and see what happens.

Comment: @Gal: see my edit above

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very very much! =)

After running `which pdflatex` I've changed `texpath` from `"$PATH:/usr/texbin"` to `"$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux"`.